# How to pull Domain portion of Url from incoming HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I looked up the various request urls that you can grab from an HttpRequest.  But I can't find how you can grab just the domain.   Also would you call that portion of the string the domain or what?  What's the formal term to call a string such as http://yourdomain.com?  I want the http:// included without me having to prefix the yourdomain.com.  I'm not sure what property I'm looking for.

Anyone know how grab that portion of the incoming HttpRequest?  What do you call it?

Answer (score 2):

`http://` is the *protocol*; `yourdomain.com` is the *host*.
You can get either of them from the `Request.Url` property.

Answer (score 0):

//your httprequest is called req you could do this.

```
Uri requesturi = req.Url;
string domain = requesturi.Host;
```